# How to improve the accuracy of grain statistics

Tags: image-processing

Grain boundaries are usually not very distinct, like [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAYWT.jpg) , [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ0do.jpg) and [pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpwDH.jpg)

[image: pic1]

I have made a edge `mask` in photoshop like the following:
[image]

Then I can detect the number of grain by `MaxDetect`:

```
point = MaxDetect[DistanceTransform[mask // ColorNegate], 2];
Colorize[count = WatershedComponents[mask, point]]
```

[image]

```
(count // Flatten // CountDistinct) - 1
```

> 346

```
HighlightImage[img, {RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.2],Dilation[ColorNegate[Image[count, "Bit"]], 2]}]
```

[image]

But the `mask` is drawn along with those gaps by my hand in photoshop. Could I get it by MMA program?

Comment: How do you define "statistical precision" in this context? What algorithm would you like to implement? Honestly this sounds like a hard scientific problem.

Comment: @MarcoB "statistical precision"  is ambiguous?  I mean I want to know how many grains are in the picture

Comment: Don't know which requirements you have to fulfill, but a very simple approach would be to estimate the length of the cracks by counting the number of dark pixels (divided by crack thickness). Then divide the area by this result.

Comment: I agree that the statistical precision you want to achieve is ambiguous.  Your current approach certainly seems to be biased high but it's impossible to know what's in your mind because the "true" set of grains is not outlined in the paired figure.

Comment: @JimB I have updated it

Comment: @MarcoB I have updated it

Comment: @lxndr  I have updated it